# How to implement recursion in U-SQL?

Tags: azure, u-sql

I have created a parameterized U-SQL procedure and I want to call it recursively by employee id. Is there a way we can implement recursion in U-SQL?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

U-SQL does indeed support recursion and you can view the Recursive TVF example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt763288.aspx#tvf_recursive).  However, recursive approaches aren't something that generally scale very well, so you may need to consider a different approach.

Paul Andrew describes another approach to recursion using Powershell [here](https://www.purplefrogsystems.com/paul/2017/05/recursive-u-sql-with-powershell-u-sql-looping/).

If you could provide some sample data and expected results, I'm sure someone will be able to help you.  I would guess you don't need a recursive approach, you simply need a set-based one.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Bob's answer (not sure if I should edit his answer or provide my own, so here I go):

1. Recursive TVFs have a nesting level limit of 50.
2. You cannot/should not call Procedures recursively, since they produce side-effects (like writing into tables or files). Instead, write a recursive TVF that produces the rowset that you then want to write in a procedure.

But as Bob mentions, please see if you can find a set-based solution or using an existing feature that does not involve recursion.